# Multiple commands in a batch file result in one line

Tags: batch-file, line, echo, dir

How can i write batch file that stores result in a file in just one line?
I want these 3 commands to write in new file ex. txt.txt in first line.

```
dir /b *.xml > txt.txt
echo 2 2 >> txt.txt
dir >> txt.txt
```

I want result to be in txt.txt file like this:

```
*.xml 2 2 dir
```

Comment: You want the output of the command `dir /b *.xml` to be printed in your file, or only "*.xml"?

Comment: output of the command

Comment: The `dir /b` command will automatically generate a multi-line entry in your file. You really wish the output to be written on a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you wanted. Instead of "dir /B" you can place any other command. Or you can use the for loop several times to append output of multiple commands in a sigle line in output file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem create or empty output file
echo.|set /p some=>file.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B') do (
    echo.|set /p some="%%a ">>file.txt
)
```